# How to share data between auth users Django

Tags: python, django

I have a list of projects in my Django which is created by some auth user, so I want to share specific projects with some other users as well. for example, I have created a "project ABC" from my frontend app so what if I want to share that "project ABC" with some other account? something like access control functionality.

you can see the account in the Project model below, so currently one account can hold the project but I want to share that Project with others as well.

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.IntegerField(default=1, null=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

i think what you're looking for is permissions. check this out https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/